# Transform values into column name

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

What query sould I write to transfer this two tables:

Table1 - EventLog

```
ID          Timestamp                Type       EventGroupID
10920061    2021-03-22 10:58:44.527  202        3F23B45E-052C-463D-BA07-A6DEC3D1356E
10920062    2021-03-22 10:58:45.207  202        C5ACC8F3-7B73-4090-ADF5-CAA7D0284AFA
10920063    2021-03-22 10:58:49.440  202        CA5AE246-8D14-41F0-B3C8-382B43EE2F52
```

Table2 - EventLogData

```
EventID     K           V
10920061    action      LiveFeedStart
10920061    cameraId    513
10920061    tracker     True
10920061    username    xxx
10920062    action      LiveFeedStart
10920062    cameraId    90
10920062    tracker     True
10920062    username    xxx
10920063    action      LiveFeedStart
10920063    cameraId    200
10920063    tracker     True
10920063    username    xxx
```

Into something like this?

```
EventID   TimeStamp                Type   Action         Tracker  CameraId  Username
10920061  2021-03-22 10:58:44.527  202    LiveFeedStart  True     513       xxx
10920062  2021-03-22 10:58:45.207  202    LiveFeedStart  True     90        xxx
```

I was only able to produce this

```
EventID     Timestamp                   Type    K   V
12943429    2021-07-12 10:57:45.4433333 203 action  LiveFeedStop
12943429    2021-07-12 10:57:45.4433333 203 bytesSent   95440687
12943429    2021-07-12 10:57:45.4433333 203 cameraId    914
12943429    2021-07-12 10:57:45.4433333 203 username    xxx
12943430    2021-07-12 10:57:51.2800000 203 action  LiveFeedStop
```

Comment: Use `PIVOT` or conditional aggregation. *Hopefully* the reason you are doing this is to fix your design, as EAV designs never work well in an RDBMS. You're breaking basic fundamental design rules here, such as mixing data types in a single column.

Comment: @larnu The table is name EventLogData, it's highly possible that this is the output from an application the OP has no control over and the App developer made extensible through using an EAV table to hold custom fields.  Would you have objected to the extensibility using strings had the string been a JSON object?  That too would involve storing varying datatypes as strings.  There are times and places that different people would argue this design pattern has merit.  Without significantly more background information on the use case, I can only conclude I'm not informed enough to have an opinion.

Comment: What happened to 10920063 in the result set?

Comment: @GordonLinoff i skipped this row

Comment: Though i partially agree, @MatBailie , if the OP wants to consume their data in a normalised format afterwards, they shouldn't be denormalising it to start with.

Answer (score 3):

```
select * from EventLog el
left join (
select eventId
       ,max(case when K = 'action' then V end) action 
       ,max(case when K = 'bytesSent' then V end) bytesSent 
       ,max(case when K = 'cameraId' then V end) cameraId 
       ,max(case when K = 'username' then V end) username 
from EventLogData
group by eventId 
) eld
on el.Id = eld=eventid
```

Comment: Both this answers looks good. I have 2kk rows in eventlog and 8kk rows in eventlogdatas. Should I just execute query and wait?

Comment: The RDBMS should be able to process 2,000 rows would pretty quickly, @lemon .

Comment: I meant milions. double k

Comment: @lemon then having an index on (eventid, K,V) would help alot

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize the `PIVOT` function to get the result. Throwing your data into a couple of tables to test with:

```
CREATE TABLE EventLog
    ([ID] int, [Timestamp] datetime, [Type] int, [EventGroupID] varchar(36))
;
    
INSERT INTO EventLog
    ([ID], [Timestamp], [Type], [EventGroupID])
VALUES
    (10920061, '2021-03-22 10:58:44', 202, '3F23B45E-052C-463D-BA07-A6DEC3D1356E'),
    (10920062, '2021-03-22 10:58:45', 202, 'C5ACC8F3-7B73-4090-ADF5-CAA7D0284AFA'),
    (10920063, '2021-03-22 10:58:49', 202, 'CA5AE246-8D14-41F0-B3C8-382B43EE2F52')
;


CREATE TABLE EventLogData
    ([EventID] int, [K] varchar(8), [V] varchar(13))
;
    
INSERT INTO EventLogData
    ([EventID], [K], [V])
VALUES
    (10920061, 'action', 'LiveFeedStart'),
    (10920061, 'cameraId', '513'),
    (10920061, 'tracker', 'True'),
    (10920061, 'username', 'xxx'),
    (10920062, 'action', 'LiveFeedStart'),
    (10920062, 'cameraId', '90'),
    (10920062, 'tracker', 'True'),
    (10920062, 'username', 'xxx'),
    (10920063, 'action', 'LiveFeedStart'),
    (10920063, 'cameraId', '200'),
    (10920063, 'tracker', 'True'),
    (10920063, 'username', 'xxx')
;
```

You then use the `PIVOT` function to convert the row values into column names:

```
select *
from
(
  select 
    el.Id,
    el.[Timestamp],
    el.Type,
    eld.K,
    eld.V
  from EventLog el
  inner join EventLogData eld
    on el.Id = eld.EventId
) d
pivot
(
  max(V)
  for K in (Action, Tracker, CameraId, Username)
) piv
```

Gives the result you're looking for. (See [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=261f917a1c445b59d57d70d61b8f68e4))

Comment: Both this answers looks good. I have 2kk rows in eventlog and 8kk rows in eventlogdatas. Should I just execute query and wait?